# Entity Framework Core Missing Argument 'PROVIDER'

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to connect my ASP.NET Core website to a database using a migration. I am using the command

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BlogDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

To generate the models etc. However I get the following error on running the command:

> Missing required argument ''

If required the startup class is just the standard template currently:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Personal_Blog
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

An example of the problem is:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BlogDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Verbose
Using project 'Personal Blog'.
Using startup project 'Personal Blog'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile "D:\Code\Personal\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Personal Blog.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\samh\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig "D:\Code\Personal\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Personal Blog.runtimeconfig.json" C:\Users\samh\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\6.0.0-preview.1.21102.2\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BlogDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --json --output-dir Models --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly "D:\Code\Personal\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Personal Blog.dll" --startup-assembly "D:\Code\Personal\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Personal Blog.dll" --project-dir "D:\Code\Personal\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\Personal Blog\\" --language C# --working-dir "D:\Code\Personal\Personal Blog\Personal Blog" --root-namespace Personal_Blog
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.CommandException: Missing required argument '<PROVIDER>'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Validate()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Missing required argument '<PROVIDER>'.
```

Could anyone advise as to what I am missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Provider - name of the provider package. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

Comment: From my understanding this is what i thought that was `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Comment: can you show your startup class?

Comment: let me know if you'd like to see anything else

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from nuget?

Comment: Yep, version 5.0.3

Comment: Please show the output of invoking `Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BlogDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Verbose`

Comment: Hi Ivan, i have added it to the description

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the command parameters. The only thing I've noticed is that you are using a preview (i.e. unstable) version of the EF Core, try switching to the latest stable release (5.0.3 at this time).

Comment: Unfortunately this produces the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I realised that I had installed the preview (6.0) packages for EF and so I downgraded them to the latest stable releases. However I still got the same error.

After restarting Visual Studio the Scaffold-DbContext command then worked fine.